Нужна помощь решить задачу по Python "Подарок лепрекона"

Задача №15 "Подарок лепрекона"
Маленький зелёный человечек за добрые дела может отблагодарить
скромным серебряным шиллингом, который будет возвращаться к владельцу,
а жадине может подарить золотой, который скоро превратится в кусок
коры или рассыплется пеплом.  Напишите программу для определения
подарка от лепрекона.
Формат ввода:
Вводятся строки: добрый, злой или Какой подарок? пока не
будет введена пустая строка.
Формат вывода
Считается количество введенных строк разного типа и на вопрос о
подарке выводится ответ.  Если строк добрый было больше, чем строк
злой, и последняя строка добрый, то подарок серебряный шиллинг.  Если
больше было строк злой и такая же последняя введенная, то подарок –
золотой.  Если вопрос задан при неопределенном значении подарка,
выводится: Ах, не знаю! и программа завершает работу.
После каждого вопроса строки считаются заново.

Пример
Ввод:
добрый           
добрый            
добрый 
злой 
добрый 
злой 
добрый 
Какой подарок? 
злой 
добрый 
злой 
злой 
добрый 
Какой подарок? 
добрый 
добрый 

Вывод:
серебряный шиллинг
Ах, не знаю!

написал следующий код:
def f():
    while True:
        good = 0
        bad = 0
        last = ''
        for word in iter(input, ''):
            if word == 'добрый':
                good += 1
                last = 'добрый'
            elif word == 'злой':
                bad += 1
                last = 'злой'
            elif word == 'Какой подарок?':
                if good > bad and last == 'добрый':
                    print('серебряный шиллинг')
                elif bad > good and last == 'злой':
                    print('золотой')
                else:
                    print('Ах, не знаю!')
                good = 0
                bad = 0
                break
        else:
            print('Ах, не знаю!')
            break


f()

но его преподователь не принимает по причине:
Ожидаемый результат
серебряный шиллинг
Ах, не знаю!

Вывод
серебряный шиллинг
Ах, не знаю!
Ах, не знаю!   


Убрать print('Ах, не знаю!') из for...else?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!
Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

"Ах, не знаю!" у тебя выводится в двух случаях. Разберись в каких именно, и сам поймешь, что нужно подправить.

def f():
    while True:
        good = 0
        bad = 0
        last = ''
        for word in iter(input, ''):
            if word == 'добрый':
                good += 1
                last = 'добрый'
            elif word == 'злой':
                bad += 1
                last = 'злой'
            elif word == 'Какой подарок?':
                if good > bad and last == 'добрый':
                    print('серебряный шиллинг')
                elif bad > good and last == 'злой':
                    print('золотой')
                else:
                    print('Ах, не знаю!')
                good = 0
                bad = 0
                break
        else:
            break


f()

После выхода из цикла не надо писать что "Ах, не знаю!", потому что у тебя в цикле идет проверка на подарок

@NursultanMoidinov Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение.
